# Is there such thing as a spreadsheet object/library

Tags: excel, csv, spreadsheet

I'm trying to generate some reporting from existing reports in CSV format.  These CSV files don't contain just data, but report name, report date, multiple data sets- each line doesn't necessarily contain the same number of fields or consistent data per row.

I was curious if there was some spreadsheet type library available, this is how I would imagine it to work.

```
load some csv file into spreadsheet

report_title = spreadsheet("A1")

report_date = spreadsheet("B2")


sales_data_spreadsheet = spreadsheet("A6:E22)")

sales_total = sales_data_spreadsheet("SUM(E1:E17)")


expenses_data_spreadsheet = spreadsheet("A26:E38")

expenses_total = expenses_data_spreadsheet("SUM(E1:E11")
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Excel?

You don't have spreadsheets, you have described flat files with mixed formats and some metadata.  What in your flat files says that the sales data is in A6:E22?  In fact what does A6:E22 mean outside the context of Microsoft Excel and in the context of your data?

There are lots of ways for you to handle this data from parsing it yourself long-hand and supplying code to manage the data formats to loading it into a set of database tables and using SQL to break it into pieces.  Which you choose depends on what the data is, where it comes from and what you are going to do with it.  If you provide a bit more of that sort of information a choice of approach may be easier to recommend.

Answer (score 1):

I've authored such [library](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) in Python & Google Spreadsheets API. An interface of the library is not exactly the same as in your example, but it uses objects for sheets and cells representation.

The library's API is pretty straightforward even if you're new to a Python.

First, you have to upload your CSVs into Google Spreadsheets, and then you can access it:

```
# Load the module
import gspread

# Login with your Google account
gc = gspread.login('_your_google_account_email_','password')

# Open a spreadsheet and worksheet
wks = gc.open("name of the spreadsheet").sheet1

wks.update_acell('B2', "it's down there somewhere, let me take another look.")

# Select a range
sales_data = [float(c.value) for c in worksheet.range('E1:E17')]

# Sum it up
sales_total = sum(sales_data)
```

Alternatively you can import your CSV data into Excel file and use this wonderful Python library: [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd)